# Notification using python

Tags: python, windows, notifications

Is it possible to add a notification in windows using python? Like a notification box with some information about an update or something

In windows if you didn't already figure that by this picture..

[image: notification]

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523511/unable-to-use-wx-notificationmessage-properly-with-wxpython

Comment: I've used this a couple of times: https://gist.github.com/1808234 It pops up a little balloon tip from the status bar.

Comment: Could one of you two put that as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [Jason Chen's](https://github.com/wontoncc) [`balloontip.py`](https://gist.github.com/wontoncc/1808234) for this. It's almost 50 lines of code so I won't be pasting it here.

Seems to work in Windows 10 as well.

Thanks to [zack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/550900/zack) for finding this gem.

Comment: needs https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/

Answer (score 52):

First, install win10toast by using `pip`:

```
pip install win10toast
```

Then, import it:

```py
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
```

Make a variable called `toast`:

```py
toast = ToastNotifier()
```

Show the `toast` variable:

```py
toast.show_toast(
    "Notification",
    "Notification body",
    duration = 20,
    icon_path = "icon.ico",
    threaded = True,
)
```

It should look something like this:

[image: python toast notification]

Comment: Will this crash in Windows 7?

Answer (score 18):

There is also [Windows-10-Toast-Notifications](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications) on Github.

It works on windows 10 (with pywin32) and it allows several notifications.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be exactly the win10toast package in user13096898's answer.

Answer (score 12):

You can use you plyer to display notifications:

```
from plyer import notification

notification.notify(
title = "Sample Notification",
message = "This is a sample notification",
timeout = 10
)
```

Or you can run this code and generate notifications:

```
from plyer import notification

import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(root , text = 'NOTIFICATION DEVELOPER').grid(row = 0, column = 0)
tk.Label(root , text = 'Notification Title:').grid(row = 3, column = 0)
tk.Label(root , text = 'Notification Message').grid(row = 4, column = 0)
tk.Label(root , text = 'Seconds for which it appears'). grid(row = 5, column = 0)

t1 = tk.Entry(root)
t1.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

m = tk.Entry(root)
m.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

tm = tk.Entry(root)
tm.grid(row = 5, column = 1)

def strt():
    a = int(tm.get())
    notification.notify(
    title = t1.get(),
    message = m.get(),
    timeout = a
    )
tk.Button(root , text = 'START NOTIFICATION' , command = strt).grid(row = 6, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

If you want he notifications to be displayed again after some time, you can use time.sleep(a) and loop the code. (a = time after which the notification will be displayed again.

For inserting icons, use app_icon:

```
app_icon = 'Full path of .ico file'
```

Comment: works without win32api