# How to background run python script?

Tags: python

I am creating an alarm using Python Tkinter. I have already completed the GUI part. Now, I want the alarm to ring automatically when the user-entered date and time arrive. How can I achieve this?

I am already aware of the Windows Task Scheduler (as I am a Windows user), but I have no idea how to integrate it into a Python script. Is it possible to automatically schedule a task using a Python script without manual intervention? If so, how can I achieve this, and which method should I use?

Comment: There are a few things to consider such as "should setting an alarm require admin?" this is required if you want to use task scheduler for each alarm. I would not recommend it for individual alarms, rather I would use task scheduler to start your program at login as a [system tray application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9494739/3220135) which runs all the time. This way admin is only needed at install time. I would use Tkinter for primary user interactions and [windows notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12575708/3220135) when the alarm goes off.

Comment: Do you need the Windows Task Scheduler somewhere? I mean, could you just play the alarm sound from python? Perhaps just use single thread dedicated to alarms, and add alarm tasks or a specific datetime from your main application using queues.

Answer (score -1):

You can start threading to run the function continuously in the background like

```
alarm_thread = threading.Thread(target=play_alarm)
alarm_thread.start()
time.sleep(1)
```

in this `play_alarm` is the function that will run in the background

```
def play_alarm():
    frequency = 1500  # Hz
    duration = 3000  # milliseconds

    while alarm_playing:
        winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
```