# How can I use Python (2.7) to read Windows notifications?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

Is there a way to read in Windows system notifications (the bubble dialogs in the lower right hand corner of the screen) using Python? I am trying to read in the text of the notification as well as the time at which it was generated, but I've been unsuccessful in locating any information on how to do this.

I have found several resources over how to *generate* these notifications, such as this question: [How to create a system tray popup message with python? (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921203/how-to-create-a-system-tray-popup-message-with-python-windows), but nothing on how to read these popups if they are generated outside of Python.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I am interested in this as well.  I've found [this gTraySpy library](https://app.assembla.com/spaces/gTraySpy/subversion/source) should do the trick, but it's not easy to wrap it in python. I hope somebody could post an example code as an answer...

Comment: Does the answer to the similar questions in the following thread answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64043297/how-can-i-listen-to-windows-10-notifications-in-python