# Listen for Windows toast/balloon notifications

Tags: python, windows, events, notifications, toast

I have an unusual question that I can't seem to find any concrete answers to.

I want to listen for toast/balloon notifications in Windows, preferably from a Python script, and get the data that is displayed to the user. Is this possible?

Comment: duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775912/how-can-i-use-python-2-7-to-read-windows-notifications)