# How can I listen to Windows 10 notifications in Python?

Tags: python, notifications, windows-10

My Python test script causes our product to raise Windows notifications ("Toasts"). How can my python script verify that the notifications are indeed raised?

I see it's possible to make a notification listener in C# using `Windows.UI.Notifications.Management.UserNotificationListener` ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener)), And I see I can make my own notifications in Python using [win10toast](https://pypi.org/project/win10toast/) - but how do I listen to othe apps' notifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [pywinrt](https://github.com/microsoft/xlang/blob/master/src/package/pywinrt/projection/readme.md) to access the [bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-at/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.management.usernotificationlistener?view=winrt-19041) in python.
A basic example would look something like this:

```py
from winrt.windows.ui.notifications.management import UserNotificationListener, UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus
from winrt.windows.ui.notifications import NotificationKinds, KnownNotificationBindings

if not ApiInformation.is_type_present("Windows.UI.Notifications.Management.UserNotificationListener"):
    print("UserNotificationListener is not supported on this device.")
    exit()

listener = UserNotificationListener.get_current()
accessStatus = await listener.request_access_async()

if accessStatus != UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus.ALLOWED:
    print("Access to UserNotificationListener is not allowed.")
    exit()

def handler(listener, event):
    notification = listener.get_notification(event.user_notification_id)

    # get some app info if available
    if hasattr(notification, "app_info"):
        print("App Name: ", notification.app_info.display_info.display_name)

listener.add_notification_changed(handler)
```

Comment: I don't work on the same product anymore, so I can't verify the answer. It does sound like the right solution, so accepted, thanks!

Comment: `listener.add_notification_changed(handler)` worked for me

Comment: @Luca Great, I've updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Searching `python windows notification listener` on google brings up only this ok-ish result but it is not complete.

Since i couldn't find any self contained example on how to do it, here is a fully working code:

```py
from winrt.windows.ui.notifications.management import UserNotificationListener
from winrt.windows.ui.notifications import KnownNotificationBindings

def handler(asd, aasd):
    unotification = asd.get_notification(aasd.user_notification_id)
    # print(dir(unotification))
    if hasattr(unotification, "app_info"):
        print("App Name: ", unotification.app_info.display_info.display_name)
        text_sequence = unotification.notification.visual.get_binding(KnownNotificationBindings.get_toast_generic()).get_text_elements()

        it = iter(text_sequence)
        print("Notification title: ", it.current.text)
        while True:
            next(it, None)
            if it.has_current:
                print(it.current.text)
            else:
                break            
    else:
        pass

listener = UserNotificationListener.get_current()
listener.add_notification_changed(handler)

while True: pass
```

tested on windows 10 and winrt v1.0.21033.1