# Tried to listen to windows notification but got element not found error

Tags: python, windows-runtime

I'm trying to create a script where it is able to listen to windows notifications and found this website ["How can i listen to windows 10 notification"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64043297/how-can-i-listen-to-windows-10-notifications-in-python)
I tried to use the guide from that website but unfortunately received an "Element not found" error. I was hoping if someone could explain to me how this error occur and the methods to fix it.

Below is the code that I used. (mostly from the website stated above)

```py
from winrt.windows.ui.notifications.management import UserNotificationListener, UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus
from winrt.windows.foundation.metadata import ApiInformation

if not ApiInformation.is_type_present("Windows.UI.Notifications.Management.UserNotificationListener"):
    print("UserNotificationListener is not supported on this device.")
    exit()

listener = UserNotificationListener.get_current()
accessStatus = listener.get_access_status()

if accessStatus != UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus.ALLOWED:
    print("Access to UserNotificationListener is not allowed.")
    exit()

def handler(listener, event):
    notification = listener.get_notification(event.user_notification_id)

    # get some app info if available
    if hasattr(notification, "app_info"):
        print("App Name: ", notification.app_info.display_info.display_name)

listener.add_notification_changed(handler)
```

Error I received:

```
listener.add_notification_changed(handler)
RuntimeError: Element not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same issue with ["How can i listen to windows 10 notification"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64043297/how-can-i-listen-to-windows-10-notifications-in-python)

I cobbled together something as a workaround based on this post: [Stack Overflow The LED](https://www.shawenyao.com/Stack-Overflow-The-LED/). It takes all the notifications and prints them out.

```
from winrt.windows.ui.notifications.management import UserNotificationListener
from winrt.windows.ui.notifications import NotificationKinds, KnownNotificationBindings

listener = UserNotificationListener.get_current()
notifications = await listener.get_notifications_async(NotificationKinds.TOAST)

for i in notifications:
    text_sequence = i.notification.visual.get_binding(KnownNotificationBindings.get_toast_generic()).get_text_elements()
    it = iter(text_sequence)
    print("Notification title: ", it.current.text)
    while True:
        next(it, None)
        if it.has_current:
            print(it.current.text)
        else:
            break
```

As for the "RuntimeError: Element not found." error perhaps the resolution to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64231605/when-i-try-to-make-a-notification-with-winrt-it-makes-an-error) is a hint to the solution, but I can't figure out how to apply it to this case.