# How can we Print The notification displayed by windows 10 using python

Tags: python, windows, automation, whatsapp

I am working on python program which gets zoom id and password from whatsapp and joins the meeting
I know i can do this with selenium like it would go to whatsapp look for latest messages and print them
But i wanted to do that other way round, The program would continously check for windows notifications, windows would display the whatsapp desktop messages instead i want use whatsapp desktop
and same is the question "How can I display the notification shown by windows"

I used selenium earlier but it was to complex and also I didn't want to use `Whatsapp Web`.

THANKS in advance

Comment: What you have tried so far? Please provide those code too.

Comment: I tried using selenium which opens whatsapp web and looks for latest messages
But That was too complex and i dint want to use whatsapp web aswell
Hope this Helps you to help me......xD:

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775912/how-can-i-use-python-2-7-to-read-windows-notifications) although there were no answers.