# dbus-python - error: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, python-3.x, notify

I am trying to send a simple desktop notification via the python notify2 module. Here is the code:

```
import notify2

notify2.init('app name')
n = notify2.Notification('Test','This is a test','C:/Users/meneu/Documents/test.PNG')
n.show()
```

Notify2 requires the dbus-python module, but here is the problem. When I try to install it via pip it throws this error:

```
creating C:\Users\meneu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-4qrgk1t2\build
creating C:\Users\meneu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-4qrgk1t2\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
error: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

My system is 64-bit and I think there lies the problem. Does anyone know how to install dbus for 64bit?  I'm using python 3.7.

I also tried out GLib and Gtk3 but that threw a lot of errors also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no DBus for Windows, and therefor no dbus-python for Windows.

Comment: Ah okay, know any viable alternatives?

Comment: I don't really know what you are trying to do, but if you want a desktop notification on windows I had this gem saved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921203/how-to-create-a-system-tray-popup-message-with-python-windows

There are probably more modern solutions out there tho, just google around.

Comment: Thanks for that link, I finally got something to work!