# Sending a Toast notification in python with an input

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, notifications

First, `win10toast` is utterly useless. I normally use a toast notification [CLI written in Go](https://github.com/go-toast/toast) for my python projects. This enables me to create buttons that open websites and put custom sounds in my notifications. However, I cannot create a input with this CLI.

I was wondering if there were any libraries or CLIs that enables me to create an input in my notifications. ( and of course interact with that input)

[image: like this]

Comment: Did you see [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57445886)?

Comment: Just saw it. Turns out the recent windows update broke it. :(
I'm sad

Comment: actually, it's not! thanks