# I need help to get vision on server client program in python

Tags: python, popup, client

I work in office
We have 11 branches, in 7 city
That each of them have about 10 pc.
They are connected under activ directory.

I want write application, that outomatically pop up screen in users desktop for seconds,  and show them message ,then disappear.

Im intermediate in python
What should i know and what libs need To be able do it?

Answer (score 0):

try to start from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921203/how-to-create-a-system-tray-popup-message-with-python-windows) for creating a pop-up in the windows system:

The result looks like this:

[image]

As one of the possible cases of implementation, the receiving these messages could be performed through [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) ([pika](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library for python)

Comment: thanks, man link work but they create very sipmle screen,i need to create screen like